# Saving integers as Strings in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I was just wondering, is there any way in MIPS to store a summation of numbers as a string and later read them byte by byte, for example:

the sum 657 -> sw into a .ascii directive -> later lb on the first index to get 6 (in ascii code) same with 5 and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: related: the generic algorithm in C (repeated division by 10, last digit = remainder).  The answer here works backwards from the end of a buffer, because the algorithm produces digits in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

Of course. The ".ascii" directive is none but a .byte directive focused on the storage of ASCII text

```
   .ascii "PP"
```

is like

```
   .byte 80,80
```

You can use `.space` to make room for your ASCII string, and then use the buffer in the convertion from integer to ASCII, if you mean this by "sw into .ascii directive" of in integer. The following code converts the "binary number" into a ASCII string using itoa and prints it (just for testing) with print_string. The function uses a buffer and returns the pointer to the first ASCII digit usable for printing. This could be used as a first helper function for a sprintf-like function implementation.

```
       .data

buffer:
         .space 32


      .text
      # the main supposes env. like spim or MARS
main:
      li   $a0, 1234      # a number
      jal  itoa
      move $a0, $v0
      li   $v0, 4         # print_string    
      syscall
      li   $v0, 10
      syscall             # exit

itoa:
      la   $t0, buffer+30  # pointer to almost-end of buffer
      sb   $0, 1($t0)      # null-terminated str
      li   $t1, '0'  
      sb   $t1, ($t0)     # init. with ascii 0
      li   $t3, 10        # preload 10

      slt  $t2, $a0, $0   # keep the sign
      beq  $a0, $0, iend  # end if 0
      bgtz $a0, loop
      neg  $a0, $a0       # absolute value (unsigned)
loop:
      div  $a0, $t3       # a /= 10
      mflo $a0
      mfhi $t4            # get remainder
      add  $t4, $t4, $t1  # convert to ASCII digit
      sb   $t4, ($t0)     # store it
      subu  $t0, $t0, 1   # dec. buf ptr
      bne  $a0, $0, loop  # if not zero, loop
      addiu $t0, $t0, 1   # adjust buf ptr
iend:
      beq  $t2, $0, nolz  # was < 0?
      addiu $t0, $t0, -1
      li   $t1, '-'
      sb   $t1, ($t0)
nolz:
      move $v0, $t0      # return the addr.
      jr   $ra           # of the string
```

After you have $v0 in the main, `lb R, ($v0)` picks "1", `lb R, 1($v0)` picks second digit (2) and so on; remember the string is null-terminated, so if you pick 0 (numeric), you have to stop

Comment: This is a bit clunky in a couple places.  You don't need to keep `'0` in a register, you can `addui $t4, $t4, '0'`.  (`'0'` is a small constant that works as an immediate).  Also, `la   $t0, buffer+30` should work.  There's no need to load the wrong address as an immediate and then add at run-time.

Comment: Other than that, this is nice (and handling signed integers is a nice bonus).  Working backwards from the end of a buffer is definitely the best approach (vs. pushing digits onto the stack or printing them one at a time.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a flaw in ShinTakezou's answer.
The line       neg  $a0, $a0
will convert the positive number to negative, which results in a weird output for the code.
If we remove this line. The codes work fine for positive integer

Comment: A better fix would be to add a branch to make the `neg` conditional on `$t2` (where the code keeps the sign of the number) so it's only done for negative numbers.  Thanks for pointing out the bug, though.

Comment: I've edited the other answer to apply this fix.  Normally that would be something to point out in a comment, but unfortunately the existence of spammers makes it impossible for SO to let new users do that until they earn some rep.  Welcome to Stack Overflow, hopefully you'll be able to contribute to other questions without having to bend the rules, especially once you have some more rep.  I upvoted this answer for that reason, even though it's not really something that should be a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation, factored into `utoa` for unsigned integers, and `itoa` for signed integers that uses `utoa`.  These provide two return values, one is the address of the string to print, and the other is a count of the number of characters in the string to print — this count is helpful when using file I/O syscalls.  The string buffer (of at least 12 characters in length) is passed in as parameter, so can be a global, or on the stack as the test `main` illustrates.

```
    .text
    j main      # jump around functions, start at main for testing itoa
```

---

```
# function utoa ( unsigned int, char* ) returns struct { char *, int }
# a0, unsigned number to convert to sring
# a1, pointer to free space large enough to hold integer as string (at least 11 bytes)
# v0, pointer to the beginning of the converted string
# v1, count of number of characters in the string
utoa:
    addiu $a1, $a1, 11  # move to the end of the buffer
    sb $0, ($a1)        # null terminator (sometimes helpful not always necessary)

    li $t0, 10
    li $v1, 0

utoaLoop:
    div $a0, $t0        # divide by 10
    mfhi $t2            # remainder is digit to print
    addiu $a1, $a1, -1  # back up one byte's worth
    addi $t2, $t2, '0'  # convert numeric digit to ascii digit
    sb $t2, ($a1)       # store in buffer
    addi $v1, $v1, 1    # increment counter of how many characters
    mflo $a0            # capture quotient
    bnez $a0, utoaLoop  # quotient not zero, so repeat to get another digit

        
    move $v0, $a1       # return pointer to start of character string
                           # note: $v1 holds count of number of characters in string
                           # the string is null terminated (but the null is not counted)
    jr $ra
```

---

```
# function itoa ( int, char* ) returns struct { char *, int }
# a0, signed number to convert to sring
# a1, pointer to free space large enough to hold integer as string (at least 12 bytes)
# v0, pointer to the beginning of the converted string
# v1, count of number of charactes in the string
# itoa calls utoa (using tco if the number is positive),
#      and otherwise prepends a '-' to the string.
itoa:
    bltz $a0, ineg
    j utoa              # tail call optimization
ineg:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -4  # space for our return address
    sw $ra, ($sp)
    neg $a0, $a0        # negate number and convert as unsigned
    jal utoa
    addiu $v0, $v0, -1  # prepend a '-' character
    li $t0, '-'
    sb $t0, ($v0)
    addi $v1, $v1, 1    # and increment character count
    lw $ra, ($sp)
    addiu $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

---

```
# a simple main for testing itoa
main:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -64 # create some stack space

    li $a0, 1234        # number to print
    move $a1, $sp   
    jal itoa
    move $a0, $v0       # return 1: where to print
    move $s0, $v1       # return 2: how many chars to print
    
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    li $a0, '\n'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $s0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    li $a0, '\n'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    li $a0, -1234
    move $a1, $sp
    jal itoa
    move $a0, $v0   # return 1: address of string to print
    move $s0, $v1   # return 2: how many chars to print

    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    
    li $a0, '\n'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall
    
    move $a0, $s0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    li $a0, '\n'
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```