# Convert an int to a string of characters

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

In MIPS assembly how would I parse an integer such as 255 into a string of characters `'2' '5' '5'`.

255 could be in `$t0`

`'2' '5' '5'` could then be stored in `$t1` and then printed.

How would I do this?

Comment: You want the 8-bit ascii version of the characters to be stored back-to-back within t1?

Comment: do you mean integer or byte? 32 bits gives you 4 characters in ascii

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I want to get 255 from t0 and put say 2 or value 0x32 as this is the character value into t1 then do the same for 5 could be put in t2 then the other 5 in t3

Comment: So you know the ascii, the bit you are stuck on is convertting 255 to 2, 5 and 5 ?

Comment: Hint: the remainders from repeated divisions by 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving integers as Strings in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934126/saving-integers-as-strings-in-mips)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the version in Python. Just translate it into mips assembly.

```
def to_str(n):
    output = ''
    while True:
        m = n % 10
        output = str(m) + output
        n = n / 10
        if n == 0:            
            break
    print(output)
```

The idea is to repeadly get remainders of division by base(in this case 10).
For example:

```
n = 255
n % 10 -> 5, n = 255 / 10 = 25
n % 10 -> 5, n = 25 / 10 = 2
2 % 10 -> 2, n = 2 / 10 = 0
```

Now, just get remainders of division and print them in reverse order.

Here is one solution in mips assembly:

```
.data
    N: .word 2554
    digits: .space 16 # number of digits * 4 bytes
    num_digits: .word 3 # number of digits - 1

.text
    lw $t0, N # $t0 = N
    lw $t1, num_digits
    sll $t1, $t1, 2
    la $s0, digits
    add $s0, $s0, $t1
loop:
    div $t2, $t0, 10
    mfhi $t2 # remainder is in $t2
    sw $t2, 0($s0)
    subi $s0, $s0, 4
    div $t0, $t0, 10
    beqz $t0, print
    b loop
print:
    # print contents of digits
    li $t0, 0 # loop counter
    lw $t1, num_digits
    la $s0, digits
print_loop:
    bgt $t0, $t1, end
    # print the digit
    lw $a0, 0($s0)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    # put a space between digits
    la $a0, 32
    li $v0, 11
    syscall

    # move the next digit and increment counter
    addi $s0, $s0, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    
    b print_loop
end:
```

This results in the following output:

```
2 5 5 4 
-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --
```

Comment: What if you don't know the number of digits? Can be retrived with floor(log_10(n))+1 but that's a pain to implement log10 in assembly for this. EDIT: I'm dumb, I can just loop through the string twice

Comment: @Winter: A common technique is to output into a temp buffer (e.g. on the stack) starting with a pointer to the end of the buffer, and doing `*p-- = x % 10 + '0'` in a loop.  Then copy to where you actually want it.  When you're done converting, you have a pointer to the most-significant digit, so you know the length.  You don't need to redo division.  Or if you just want to print it, you can pass that pointer to somewhere, since storing digits in decreasing order results in a string in printing order.  (This answer makes an array of int like that, missing the final step of make a char array)

Comment: MIPS `div` produces quotient (in `lo`) and remainder (in `hi`) with one instruction.    You don't need to divide twice.  https://godbolt.org/z/a8v64n6cb shows how GCC uses quotient and remainder from one `div`.  Your code doesn't use `mflo` at all, which may be a bug.  (It also doesn't actually produce a string in memory, just output on the console with the print_int system call.)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of converting a number into a string in some base is basically done by repeatedly dividing it by the base (10 in this case) and write the remainder backwards until the value is zero. That's the easiest solution. For example for 255

```
255/10 = 25 remain 5 ↑
 25/10 =  2 remain 5 ↑
  2/10 =  0 remain 2 ↑
```

The remainder is 2, 5, 5 as expected

For decimal you have another option, that is [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble), which can convert binary into [packed BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) without division. Then you can unpack the nibbles into chars easily

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk did a very good job! I'm just writing to make his answer more complete.

The message

```
     -- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --
```

is shown because he didn't end his program with

```
                  li $v0, 10
                  syscall
```

You should always finish your program with the above lines to terminate the execution normally.

From http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm:

```
e.g. To indicate end of program, use exit system call; thus last lines of program should be:

    li $v0, 10     # system call code for exit = 10
    syscall        # call operating sys
```

Comment: Why not up-vote him if he did such a great job? Also, this should really be a comment on his answer -- it doesn't answer the question by itself.