# Does mips have any syscall/function like Itoa in c?

Tags: assembly, mips

Does mips have any syscall/function like Itoa in c?

I have to convert 4 integers to strings , so that I can write that integers to a file.

Comment: No. Formatting strings is no job for the kernel or instruction set. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, if you have a C library, obviously.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934126/saving-integers-as-strings-in-mips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itoa` is a function from the C standard library. It is not directly implemented in the kernel because it does not need access to it.  It's just computation stuff.

System calls are provided for user programs to interact with the kernel when it needs access to resources the kernel manages (like secondary storage, I/O ports, memory management, and much I/O stuff in general).

Therefore, it just depends on the fact whether you have a C library or not. The (AFAIK) most popular implementation, the GNU C library glibc, does support MIPS but [not in the main tree since glibc 2.5](https://lfs.pilgrims.ru/clfs/view/svn/mips/cross-tools/glibc.html).