# Simple mips function to convert integer to string

Tags: assembly, mips

I've been trying to do some simple tasks to help me learn mips (from a java background). But I can't figure out how one converts a normal integer to a string with mips.

I'm looking for an as-simple-as-possible function/method (or whatever mips calls them) that I can use as part of a larger piece of code.

Comment: The algorithm to convert an integer to a string representation in base `B` is simple: keep dividing by `B` and place the remainder (converted to a character) in memory in backwards order. Stop when the quotient is 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving integers as Strings in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934126/saving-integers-as-strings-in-mips)

Comment: Java is conceptually pretty far away from assembly language because it hides a lot of detail in the run time environment and libraries. When I've taught assembly language, those with a C background (not C++) had a much easier time with early tasks like this. I recommend you learn how to do this in C first. Getting to mips from there is a much shorter hop.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is late, but I will attempt to answer this. Firstly, the MIPS pseudocode to convert an integer to string is as follows -

```
void int2str(num, str):   // str: pointer to string version of integer 'num'
  if num < 0:
    *str = ASCII of '-'   // negative number
    str++
    num *= -1
  push -1 to MIPS stack   // end of stack marker
  while num > 0:
    push num % 10 to MIPS stack
    num = num // 10

  digit = pop from MIPS stack
  if digit < 0:
    *str = ASCII of 0     // number was 0
    str++
  else:
    while digit >= 0:
      *str = ASCII of digit
      str++
      digit = pop from MIPS stack
  *str = 0                // since strings are null terminated
```

Once the above is clear, we can easily translate this to MIPS:

```
# inputs : $a0 -> integer to convert
#          $a1 -> address of string where converted number will be kept
# outputs: none
int2str:
addi $sp, $sp, -4         # to avoid headaches save $t- registers used in this procedure on stack
sw   $t0, ($sp)           # so the values don't change in the caller. We used only $t0 here, so save that.
bltz $a0, neg_num         # is num < 0 ?
j    next0                # else, goto 'next0'

neg_num:                  # body of "if num < 0:"
li   $t0, '-'
sb   $t0, ($a1)           # *str = ASCII of '-' 
addi $a1, $a1, 1          # str++
li   $t0, -1
mul  $a0, $a0, $t0        # num *= -1

next0:
li   $t0, -1
addi $sp, $sp, -4         # make space on stack
sw   $t0, ($sp)           # and save -1 (end of stack marker) on MIPS stack

push_digits:
blez $a0, next1           # num < 0? If yes, end loop (goto 'next1')
li   $t0, 10              # else, body of while loop here
div  $a0, $t0             # do num / 10. LO = Quotient, HI = remainder
mfhi $t0                  # $t0 = num % 10
mflo $a0                  # num = num // 10  
addi $sp, $sp, -4         # make space on stack
sw   $t0, ($sp)           # store num % 10 calculated above on it
j    push_digits          # and loop

next1:
lw   $t0, ($sp)           # $t0 = pop off "digit" from MIPS stack
addi $sp, $sp, 4          # and 'restore' stack

bltz $t0, neg_digit       # if digit <= 0, goto neg_digit (i.e, num = 0)
j    pop_digits           # else goto popping in a loop

neg_digit:
li   $t0, '0'
sb   $t0, ($a1)           # *str = ASCII of '0'
addi $a1, $a1, 1          # str++
j    next2                # jump to next2

pop_digits:
bltz $t0, next2           # if digit <= 0 goto next2 (end of loop)
addi $t0, $t0, '0'        # else, $t0 = ASCII of digit
sb   $t0, ($a1)           # *str = ASCII of digit
addi $a1, $a1, 1          # str++
lw   $t0, ($sp)           # digit = pop off from MIPS stack 
addi $sp, $sp, 4          # restore stack
j    pop_digits           # and loop

next2:
sb  $zero, ($a1)          # *str = 0 (end of string marker)

lw   $t0, ($sp)           # restore $t0 value before function was called
addi $sp, $sp, 4          # restore stack
jr  $ra                   # jump to caller
```

Finally, this can be called as -

```
.data
str:   .space 128         # bytes for string version of the number

.text
main:
li   $a0, -1102           # $a0 = int to convert
la   $a1, str             # $a1 = address of string where converted number will be kept
jal  int2str              # call int2str

la   $a0, str             # once returned, str has the string version. Print it.
li   $v0, 4               # $v0 = 4 for printing string pointed to by $a0
syscall                   # after this, the console has '-1102'
```